# Getting duplicate links for images in scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a Prestashop website where I want to get a list URLs for all images of a product. However, I am getting duplicate values (all links repeat themselves). I have tried creating a dictionary to remove duplicates, but it does not seem to work.
Also I can't seem to remove the span tags from the reference number (unwrap does not work) - it keeps returning 'None' attribute, which is confusing, because all products have a reference number. I have tried turning the result into a string, but it does not let me.

Here is the code:

```
testlink = 'https://trgovina.audiopro.si/si/bas-glave/36037-81020104.html'

r = requests.get(testlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
imagelinks = []
name = soup.find('h1', class_='product_name').text.strip()
reference = soup.find('div', class_='product-reference_top product-reference')
reference_number = reference.find('span')
images = soup.find_all('li', class_='thumb-container')
for item in images:
    image = item.find('img').attrs['src']
    imagelinks.append(image)
print(imagelinks)
```

Comment: can you add also the part with import packages? it will be easier to debug.

Comment: why not use `.text` to remove tag.

Comment: you can always use `set()` instead of list `[]` to remove duplicate items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text` to get number without tag `<span>`

```
reference_number = reference.find('span').text
```

Use `set()` instead of list to skip duplicate items

```
imagelinks = set()

# ... 

    imagelinks.add(image)
```

---

Full working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

testlink = 'https://trgovina.audiopro.si/si/bas-glave/36037-81020104.html'

r = requests.get(testlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

imagelinks = set()

name = soup.find('h1', class_='product_name').text.strip()

reference = soup.find('div', class_='product-reference_top product-reference')
reference_number = reference.find('span').text
print(reference_number)

images = soup.find_all('li', class_='thumb-container')

for item in images:
    image = item.find('img').attrs['src']
    imagelinks.add(image)

print(imagelinks)
print('len:', len(imagelinks))
```

---

**EDIT:**

OR you should get images only from `<div id="thumb_box">`

using `find().find_all()`

```
images = soup.find('div', {'id':'thumb_box'}).find_all('li', class_='thumb-container')
```

or using `CSS selector`

```
images = soup.select('div#thumb_box li.thumb-container')
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

testlink = 'https://trgovina.audiopro.si/si/bas-glave/36037-81020104.html'

r = requests.get(testlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

imagelinks = []

name = soup.find('h1', class_='product_name').text.strip()

reference = soup.find('div', class_='product-reference_top product-reference')
reference_number = reference.find('span').text
print(reference_number)

images = soup.find('div', {'id':'thumb_box'}).find_all('li', class_='thumb-container')
#images = soup.select('div#thumb_box li.thumb-container')

for item in images:
    image = item.find('img').attrs['src']
    imagelinks.append(image)

print(imagelinks)
print('len:', len(imagelinks))
```

Comment: I added line with `CSS selector`